# I want to disable specific holidays, and days of the week in jQuery Datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, gravityforms

I am using a gravity form that is using a jQuery datepicker field. I would like to disable same day, Sunday, Saturday, Wednesday, and these holidays: Labor Day (Sep 7), Oct 2, Thanksgiving and the day after (Nov 26,27), Christmas (Dec 25), New Years (Jan 1).

```
 var dateToday = new Date();
 dateToday.setDate(dateToday.getDate() + 1);
 jQuery("#input_2_1").datepicker({
     dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
     minDate: dateToday,
     beforeShowDay: function(date) {
     return [!(date.getDay()==0||date.getDay()==6||date.getDay()==3||date.getDate() == "2020-09-07"||date.getDate() == "2020-11-26"||date.getDate() == "2020-11-27"||date.getDate() == "2020-12-25"||date.getDate() == "2020-01-01")]
  }
 });
```

However, I also want to **enable** these Wednesdays: Sep 9, Nov 25, Dec 23. I'm not sure how to accomplish this considering that I have Wednesdays disabled above.

I'm definitely doing something wrong here. How should I set this up differently to accomplish this?

Comment: Check out Gravity Forms Limit Dates: https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-limit-dates/ It will allow you to set general rules and exceptions to those rules right from the field settings.

Comment: I would, but I unfortunately can't afford to purchase currently :(

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
    // set unavailable dates
    var unavailableDates = ['26-11-2020','24-12-2020','25-12-2020'];
    var availableDates = ['9-9-2020','25-11-2020'];

    // check unavailable dates and verify if the weekday is approved
    function unavailable(date) {

        // beforeShowDay, get date
        dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();

        // inArray returns the index of the element, or -1, if element not found
        // if today is found in unavailableDates, return false
        if (jQuery.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) != -1) {

            return [false];

        // if today is found in todays availableDates, return true
        } else if (jQuery.inArray(dmy, availableDates) != -1) {

                return [true];  

        } else {

            // if day is Sunday, Saturday, Wednesday, diable the day
            if( date.getDay() == 0 || date.getDay() == 3 || date.getDay() == 6 ) {
                return [false];
            } else{
                return [true];
            }   
        }
    }


    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        $("#input_2_1").datepicker({

            minDate : 1,
            beforeShowDay: unavailable,

        }); 

    });
```